# JSON Array won't display in UITable swift

Tags: arrays, json, swift, swift2

Im trying to create a table which fills in its data from an online JSON file. I currently have the JSON file online and being called into the class and getting converted into an array, however when I try set my text as this array data nothing displays.

```
cell.textLabel?.text = "\(locationName[indexPath.row])"
```

However if I set the data in the array it works however I need the data to be from the JSON file.

```
var array: double = ["1", "2", "3"]
```

Here is my table class code with the array code. Any help would be great thanks

```
class SpotsDataClass: UITableViewController {

    var locationName = [String]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://woamph.com/savedLocations.json")
            .response { request, response, data, error in

                if let data = data {

                    let json = JSON(data: data)

                    for locationLoop in json {
                        let usersJSON = locationLoop.1["user"].stringValue
                        self.locationName.append(usersJSON)
                        //let longitudeJSON = locationLoop.1["longitude"].doubleValue
                        //self.array2.append(longitudeJSON)
                    }

                    for i in 0 ..< self.locationName.count {
                        print("\(self.locationName[i])")
                        //print("\(self.array2[i])")
                        //self.locationNameLabel.text = "Location Name: \(self.array1[i])"
                    }

                    //self.titleLabel.text = "Spots Near You"
                    //self.locationNameLabel.text = "Location Name: \(spotData.locationName)"
                    //self.ratingLabel.text = "Rating: \(spotData.rating)"
                    //self.userLabel.text = "Posted By: \(spotData.user)"
                    //
                }
        }
    }

    //Mark: - UITableDataSource

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return locationName.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("spotTable", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

        cell.textLabel?.text = "\(locationName[indexPath.row])"
        return cell
    }


}
```

Comment: instead of "`cell.textLabel?.text = "\(locationName[indexPath.row])"` why not simply do "`cell.textLabel?.text = locationName[indexPath.row]`" Also, set an Xcode breakpoint and make certain that `usersJSON` is not nil.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann I put it in "\()" to see if i had to string interpolate, and I shall do thank you for the advice,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Alamofire request executes asynchronously. You need to explicitly tell your table view to reload when the network request is done, otherwise you're populating your array from the results but the table view has already been loaded by the time your remote data has been loaded.

So, after

```
for locationLoop in json {
  let usersJSON = locationLoop.1["user"].stringValue
  self.locationName.append(usersJSON)
}
```

Add: 
`tableView.reloadData()`